# Spring request mapping containing square brackets

Tags: java, spring, request-mapping

A project I am working on has a @RequestMapping mapping for a rest method that looks like:

```
  /v{version:[1-9]}
```

Can somebody explain what this is doing, does it mean the url can contain 1-9 in that place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **version** is a variable name, as a Path Parameter in the URL.
The bracketed portion is a regex expression. In this case a single number from any within the range of 1 to 9.

So that portion of the URL is valid with something like, **/v4** and you have access to the numeric portion in your code as a variable named **version**.

Comment: Ok thanks, I did think this was probably the case but the method doesnt do anything with the version variable, it isnt even passed as a path variable into the controller method so I wasnt entirely sure what was happening here.